# VirtualBox Python API on Mac M1: attempting to import VBoxPython3.so, but getting error: "incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')"

Tags: macos, virtualbox, apple-m1

I am attempting to use the VirtualBox Python API on a Mac M1. When attempting to import VBoxPython3.so, there is an ImportError that reads as follows:
`ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxPython2_7.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxPython2_7.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))`

As previously mentioned, I am on an ARM64 architecture, with an ARM64 install of VirtualBox, so why do I get this message saying `need 'x86_64'`?

System details:

- the output of `uname -a` is `Darwin KiransMacbookPro.local 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Thu Jan  5 20:48:54 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.2~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64`
- the output of `uname -m` is `arm64`

I first installed python 3.11 via conda. Then, I followed these steps:

1. I installed the ARM64 beta version of VirtualBox at https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-7.0.97_BETA5-158690-macOSArm64.dmg
2. I set the relevant environment variable: `export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS`
3. I navigated to `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/sdk/installer` and then ran `sudo -E python vboxapisetup.py install`
4. I ran `pip install virtualbox` and then confirmed that both the virtualbox and vboxapi packages were installed via `pip list`
5. I ran `python -m "import virtualbox; _vbox = VirtualBox(); print('Success')"` to see whether instantiating a VirtualBox worked

This resulted in an error in `vboxxpcom.py`, which read: `Cannot find VBoxPython module (tried: VBoxPython3_11, VBoxPython3, VBoxPython)`.

I first confirmed the following file existed: `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxPython3.so`. Then, I tried importing it manually as follows: `python -m "import sys; sys.path.append('/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS'); __import__('VBoxPython3')"`. This is the same import causing the error in `vboxxpcom.py`. This line returned:
`ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxPython2_7.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxPython2_7.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))`

Comment: This issue has been reproduced both in VSCode Terminal and Mac Terminal, so I don't think that is the explanation. `uname -m` returns `arm64` both in VSCode and in an outside Terminal.

Comment: Is your `python` binary `x86_64`-only?

Comment: Yes, it was, thanks for the help! I reinstalled an `arm64` version of `python` and this issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out my `python` library was an `x86_64` version. Try installing the `arm64` version of python (or in my case, conda).